# С# reflection: безопасность использования

Tags: c#

В чем заключается безопасность использования Отражения в С#?

Comment: В смысле? Разве использование рефлексии должно представлять собой какую-то опасность?

Comment: не опасность, а наоборот, какие преимущества она дает по безопасности по сравнению с другими методами?

Comment: @Marina_L: А какие есть другие методы? Методы _чего_?

Comment: @Marina_L какие-то у вас вопросы однообразные. Откуда они? 

А если по сабжу - то отражения в C# как раз более опасны, нежели многие другие средства языка. В частности, они могут нарушать инкапсуляцию

Comment: вопросы задает преподаватель, которому защищаем лабораторные, так что что спросили, то и отвечаем. Но всё таки надо ответить- в чем же безопасность отражения? ну иначе бы не использовали его...вообще

Comment: @Marina_L что вы понимаете под "безопасностью"? Безопасность по сравнению с чем? Я вам уже сказал чуть выше - рефлесксия (отражения то есть) - штука довольно опасная в сравнении с прочими средствами этого языка. Боюсь, вы задаете вопрос, смысла которого сами не понимаете.

Answer (score 2):

Ну это смотря с чем сравнивать. Поскольку C# — безопасный язык, то программа даже при использовании reflection не должна скатиться в undefined behaviour (как это может случиться в C++ при использовании `reinterpret_cast`). Однако, меняя приватные данные классов при помощи reflection, вы *можете* легко спровоцировать неправильную работу затронутых классов, так что undefined behaviour скатывается с уровня языковых конструкций на уровень нарушения инвариантов объектов.

С другой стороны, компоненты, не имеющие full trust, не могут применять рефлексию к более привилегированным компонентам, так что защита на этом уровне есть.